# I want to update my postcontent with $wpdb

Tags: wpdb

When I post a post to my site though webapi,there already had a same post_title in my post list, So I just want to update my post_content or replace all data to the old post but not let wp create a new post which post_name became post_name-1.

I got this code with wpdb, but it's not work, please help me, thank you guys!

```
$checkTitle = true;    
if($checkTitle)
            {
        $post_title = trim(hm_strip_slashes($post_title));
        $sql = "SELECT `ID` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_title` = '$post_title'";
        $t_row = $wpdb->query($sql);
        if($t_row) {$wpdb->get_results("update $wpdb->posts set `post_content` = $post_content WHERE `post_title` = $post_title");};
            }
```

Comment: Try taking the single quotes around `'$post_title'` off. Single quotes tell PHP to read a string literally instead of parsing it and applying the variable.

Comment: You need [`$wpdb->update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) not `get_results`. But this feels wrong: where have you put this code? Which is the web API you're using - the REST API, [POST /wp/v2/posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post)? Are you modifying the handler for that to do the overwrite? Could you change your client to make an update call instead?

Comment: I get this form someone, this code is for a client which can post blog from localhost.I can upload this post.php in root of my wordpres site

Comment: download here https://send.firefox.com/download/2bd675a86da59f4f/#WebLOL_U7HuJyKptlGOVFA